# Outlook web access adding its own <p> style into all outgoing mail

Tags: outlook-web-app

Windows Small Business Server 2011

Hi had a strange problem this morning someone reported that when they send an email from OWA their signature was coming out incorrectly, there was no spacing between certain elements etc...

After having a look a the emails html I notices that OWA seems to be appendning it's own

style as shown below:

```
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 9.00.8112.16450">
<style id="owaParaStyle">P {
    MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px
}
</style>
</head>
```

this style is causing the signature to look incorrect. After a search of the net I can find no way to fix this?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline-styles have higher priority, I believe, so you *might* have some luck by changing your HTML-signature from, say:

```
<p>My Company</p>...
```

to:

```
<p style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">My Company</p>...
```

Comment: That's not a bad workaround, I can quite easily implement that, I will accept it later on unless someone can tell me a way to stop OWA from actually doing this in the first place. Thanks again Nick